# Anyway to solve this problem without calculation?

Tags: probability

The problem is

> Airlines find that each passenger who reserves a seat fails to turn up with probability 0.1 independently from other passengers. So Teeny Weeny Airlines always sell 10 tickets for their 9 seat aero plane while Blockbuster Airways always sell 20 tickets for their 18 seat airplane. Which one is more often overbooked?

The brutal way to solve this is trivial.The probability for Teeny Weeny Airlines to be overbooked is $p_1=0.9^{10}≈0.3487$, and the probability for Blockbuster Airways to be overbooked is $p_2=0.9^{20}+C_{20}^{19}×0.9^{19}×0.1≈0.3917$. So Blockbuster Airways should be more often overbooked.

My question is -- is there any more graceful solution without really calculating the probability? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you can use expected value since you know the distribution of the random variable. It would be easier this way.

Comment: It should be $C_{19}^{20}$.

Comment: @Tony my thoughts on the problem are that the point is that the result (which is easy enough to compute directly) is *counterintuitive*.  In particular, the law of large numbers tells us that if an airline sells $N$ tickets for $\frac 9{10}N$ seats, then as $N \to \infty$ the probability of overbooking approaches zero. However, this convergence to zero is not necessarily monotonic, as exemplified here.

Comment: @Om Actually, CLT tells us that as $N\to \infty$, probability of overbooking goes to $1/2$ and it can be argued it grows monotonically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Qualitative approach:** let the number of passengers not showing up for airline $i$ ($=1,2$) be $$N_i\sim Binom(i\cdot n,\frac 1 {n})$$ with $n=10$ in our case. Note that $N_i$ is centered around $i$ - its mean, mode and median are equal to $i$. When you double the number of passengers, you squish and spread out distribution of $N_1$ into that of $N_2$ - hence the probability of getting the mean/median number of missing passengers *exactly* goes down (i.e. $P(N_1=1)>P(N_2=2)$). This probability must get distributed both to the right and to the left of this mean/median value - hence $$p_1=P(N_1<1)<P(N_2<2)=p_2$$

**2. Poisson approximation** to the binomial: $N_i\approx Pois(i)$:
$$p_1=P(N_1=0)\approx e^{-1}$$
$$p_2= P(N_2=0,1)\approx e^{-2}(1+\frac {2^1} {1!})>e^{-1}$$

**3. Exact analysis**:

$$p_1=(1-\frac 1 n)^n=e^{n\log(1-\frac 1 n)}>e^{-1-\frac 1 {2(n-1)}}>e^{-1}(1-\frac 1 {2(n-1)})$$
$$p_2=p_1p_1+2np_1p_1\frac {1/n}{1-1/n}=p_1p_1(1+\frac 2 {1-1/n})>p_1e^{-1}(1-\frac 1{2(n-1)})(3+\frac 2 {n-1})=p_1e^{-1}(3+\frac 1 {2(n-1)}-\frac 1 {(n-1)^2})\ge\frac 3 ep_1$$
 for all $n\geq 3$.

Check $n=2$ separately to get $$\frac {p_2} {p_1}>\frac 3 e > 1.1$$ for all $n\ge 2$.

Answer (score 1):

*Simplified to conform to the exact binomial distribution*

SD for a binomial distribution  $= \sqrt (npq)$

$p$ and $q$ are the same for both airlines, but since Blockbuster Airways[$B$] has double the $n$, its SD will be larger, $\sqrt2$ times of that of Teeny Weeny [T].

Since the deviation from the mean to overbook is the same for both, viz.$1$,

$\dfrac{z_T}{z_B} = \sqrt2$, i.e. overbooking occurs closer to the mean for Blockbuster Airways,

and thus P($B$ overbooked) > P($T$ overbooked)

Comment: But distributions in question are not even close to normal.

Comment: I know; they are both binomial distributions with the same $p$, only $n$ is different, due to which z-value for over booking is in the ratio of $\sqrt2$, so is the conclusion unreasonable ?

Comment: Unreasonable without further argumentation. Variance by itself doesn't control probability of deviation from below - only from above.

Comment: I have seen your comment against the question, and agree with it. I think you should post a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that people are booked in groups of ten, and that two such groups are due to show up at 12:00 noon. The following turnouts  may cause  overbookings:
$$(10,10), \quad(10,9), (9,10),\quad (10,\leq8),(\leq8,10)\ .$$
With $(10,10)$ all planes will be overbooked. With $(10,9)$,  $(9,10)$ the BBA plane and one of the TWA planes would be oberbooked, and with $(10,\leq8)$, $(\leq8,10)$ only one of the TWA planes would be overbooked. Since the latter figures are much less probable than $(10,9)$,  $(9,10)$ their occurrence cannot outweigh the advantage TWA got in the $(10,9)$,  $(9,10)$ case.

Comment: But $\frac {P(10,9)}{P(10,\le 8)}$ is somewhat close to 1 as you are comparing the peak of the distribution to the whole long tail to the right of it. Poisson approximation gives the ratio of 1.39.